# Is it convenient to use java.lang.Void for classes that doesn't return anything?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm developing a clustering framework and I have the following interface 
in order to provide a way to execute a piece of code on another node in the cluster:

```
interface Operation<V> {
    V run();
    int getService();
}
```

However,  the user may not care about the result of an operation. 
In this case I need to provide a convenient way for them. I have two options:

I can tell them to use java.lang.Void as parameter and check the return type in remote server and return the result if the generic type is not Void:

```
new Operation<Void> {
    public Void run() {
      //
      return null;
    }
    public int getService() { return 1; }
}
```

However, even if they use java.lang.Void, 
they still need to return something in run method so 
it might not be a good way to do something like that.

Also I can create another interface that doesn't not return anything.
However, now we have two types and I'm afraid it can be much for complex than the first way.

```
interface FireAndForgetOperation {
    void run();
    int getService();
}
```

Which way do you think is more convenient?

Comment: I think this is opinion-based, but two interfaces is about twice as many as one, and forcing an implementer to explicitly return `Void` really doesn't seem that onerous.

Comment: If I were you, I would go with Java8's `Optional<T>` type

Comment: Then users have to return Optional.empty(), right @kocko?

Comment: Yes, depending on the existence of value.

Comment: Using Void is common when implementing a Callable, for example. Using an Optional forces every implementation to return an Optional even when it's guaranteed to return a non-null value. I would not do that. Void is the appropriate type to say "I return nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first approach is convenient. It is used inside some java libraries. One example is the Callback  interface in JavaFX (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Callback.html).
Code that needs to use a callback and does want any returned value declares the callback as:

```
CallBack<SomeClass, Void> myCallBack;
```

And in the call method you return null;

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely do something like this to avoid exposing something that doesn't have to be:

```
public interface Operation<V> {
    V run();
    public int getService();
}

abstract public class VoidOperation implements Operation<Void> {

    public final Void run() {
        runVoid();
        return null;
    }

    abstract public void runVoid();

    abstract public int getService();
}
```

Usage :

```
    new Operation<String>() {
        public String run() {
          return null;
        }
        public int getService() { return 1; }
    };

    new VoidOperation() {
        public void runVoid() {
        }
        public int getService() { return 1; }
    };
```